# Android app switches to previous screen while running at the background for a time period

Tags: android, background, sensors

I am developing an android app, which in the main screen shows a map View and has two buttons, one for switching to the Sensors Screen( which displays various data and graphs from the mobile sensor) and one one for the map utility.

While running the app in the background in the sensor data screen (the app stores the sensor data into a database file periodically) after some period, when i bring the app in the foreground i find out that it has switched back to the main screen...why does this happen?

How can i avoid it?

Comment: how can anyone knows if you don't provide any code about how it works?

Comment: I think your app is getting killed in the background. that's why when you open the app start destination from the navigation graph is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun setIntroScreenButtonListeners()
{
    introScreenLayoutBinding.SensorsBTN.setOnClickListener {
        switchToMainScreen()
    }

    introScreenLayoutBinding.MapBTN.setOnClickListener {
        onPause()
        switchToMapFragment()
```

}
}

```
private fun periodicStorageOfData()
{
    var handler = Handler()
    var runnableCode : Runnable = object : Runnable
    {
        override fun run() {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                storeAllDataToSQlDatabase()
            }
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
        }

    }
    handler.post(runnableCode)
}

    //fragment transaction method
    private fun switchToMapFragment()
    {
        sensorAppRunning = false
        mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance()
//        locationMapFragment = LocationMapFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(introScreenLayoutBinding.fragmentFrameLayout.id , mapFragment).commit()
    }
```